# What's the squiz matrix keyword format to use to get image varieties with a dynamic asset id?

Tags: content-management-system

The manual says to use the keyword %image_v_[variety-name]_url% to get the URL of a specific image variety, but what is the keyword format when you want the url for an image variety and all you have is a dynamic asset id in a metadata field?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ^as_asset format to get the value.

```
%asset_metadata_[metdatafield]^as_asset:image_v_[variety-name]_url%
```

for example

```
%asset_metadata_award.image^as_asset:image_v_img-md_url%
```